# EntityFramework with WEB API, update all properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using EF with WEB API. 
I have a PUT Method which updates a entity which already is in the db. 
Right now I have this:

```
        // PUT api/fleet/5
        public void Put(Fleet fleet)
        {
            Fleet dbFleet = db.Fleets.Find(fleet.FleetId);
            dbFleet.Name = fleet.Name;
            dbFleet.xy= fleet.xy;
            //and so on....
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

But I'm lazy and would just like to write something like:

```
dbFleet.update(fleet);
```

So I don't have to update every property by its own.

I'm sure there is a way but I could only find answers on how to do this with MVC but not when using a WEB API and not receiving the model state.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just found the answer...

```
// PUT api/fleet/5
public void Put(Fleet fleet)
{
    db.Entry(fleet).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Only thing I'm not happy with is that it doesn't update child object.
Fleet has FleetAttributes which are not updated like this. But I guess I can easily loop them...

EDIT this works for me:

```
// PUT api/fleet/5
public void Put(Fleet fleet)
{
    db.Entry(fleet).State = EntityState.Modified;
    foreach (var item in fleet.FleetAttributes)
    {
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Nice! I was also stuck at updating child object. You did it very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

```
db.Fleets.Attach(fleet);
db.Entry(fleet).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Will this also recursively mark dependant entities as modified?